# how can fetch data from database chunlby chunk by chunk using Python PETL or pygramETL or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pygrametl

is their any way to fetch data from db using chunkwise

i have around 30 million data in my db it will cause big memory usage without using this
i tried with pandas version 0.17.1

```
for sd in psql.read_sql(sql,myconn,chunksize=100):
    print sd
```

but throwing

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/subin/PythonIDE/workspace/python/pygram.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/subin/PythonIDE/workspace/python/pygram.py", line 20, in <module>
    for sd in psql.read_sql(sql,myconn,chunksize=100):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1565, in _query_iterator
    parse_dates=parse_dates)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 137, in _wrap_result
    coerce_float=coerce_float)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 969, in from_records
    coerce_float=coerce_float)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5279, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5357, in _list_to_arrays
    content = list(lib.to_object_array_tuples(data).T)
TypeError: Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got tuple)
```

please help me

Comment: And if use `pandas`, still error? `for sd in pd.read_sql(sql,myconn,chunksize=100): print sd` ?

Comment: Is possible upgrade?